# SQL Cross Join with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table AddressTypes with 4 records (home,office,vacation,hotel) and a table Address that share the filed addresstypeid.

In address table I have 1 record of type "home" and I want a query where I get 4 rows like this:

```
Type     Address1  Address2 City    State

home     piping    1232     Austin  Tx
office   null      null     null    null
vacation null      null     null    null
hotel    null      null     null    null
```

Here is an image of tables: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=28078xv&s=6

I'm sure is something very easy maybe using cross join but don't get it. Hope someone can guide me. Appreciate in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question, could you show samples of the two tables you want to produce this result.

Comment: You may want to edit you title, so it doesn't suggest a possibly incorrect solution (Cross join may not be the answer).

Comment: Here are the tables http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=28078xv&s=6

Comment: Instead of tinypic, use http://sqlfiddle.com You can also use its Text to DDL to automate DDL creation

Comment: If you're trying to do this for many different address-bearing entities at once, we must know the third table that the addresses relate to, that has one row per entity the addresses are for! What is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Left joining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) AdddressTypes to Addresses will produce desired result:

```
select at.Type, 
       a.Address1, 
       a.Address2, 
       a.City, 
       a.State
  from AddressTypes at
  left join Address a
    on at.AddressTypeID = a.AddressTypeID
-- For this query to make sense
-- Filter one person only
   and a.PersonID = @PersonID
```

----------- THIS PART WAS ADDED BY VAAA ------------------------

Nikola, I change to this:

```
select at.description, 
       a.Address1, 
       a.Address2, 
       a.City
  from address_types at
  left join Address a
    on 1 = 1
-- For this query to make sense
-- Filter one person only
   and a.addressid = 24
```

And then I get the 4 rows, but all of them have the same address info and just the "home" type address is the one with data. So its close...

Comment: Nikola that will output just 1 row. Just tried it. Here are the tables schema. http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=28078xv&s=6

Comment: @VAAA My mistake - I had put a filter on right table to where. Please check updated answer (where is changed to and).

Comment: Nikola, i dont see the updated answer.. just my edit :) Maybe I edit when you were updating :)

Comment: @VAAA Refresh the page or just change `where` in your query (if you put one, that is) to `and`.

Comment: @VAAA Why `1 = 1`? There must be something along the lines of `at.AddressTypeID = a.AddressTypeID`...

Comment: If you will do it like this: `address_types at left join Address a on 1 = 1`, might as well do cross join instead: `address_types at cross join address a`. That way, you won't need the `1 = 1`

Comment: `CROSS JOIN`ing with AddressTypes and Address is **completely wrong**.

Comment: @ErikE RE: **completely wrong**, is that a proof-by-blatant assertion? I'm not in anyway suggesting that `CROSS JOIN`ing AddressTypes to Address is correct, I don't have an intimate knowledge of the database structure of the OP, I will not blatantly suggest that.  What I said is if you will suggest this: `tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON alwaysTrueConditionHere`, you might as well use `CROSS JOIN`. `X LEFT JOIN Y ON 1 = 1` will degenerate to `X CROSS JOIN Y`. Wanted to downvote your comment, but alas I cannot ;-) Here's the proof: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa2ed/2

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović `left join Address a on 1 = 1 and a.addressid = 24`, the `1 = 1` can be eliminated. If that really is the correct answer, you might as well just do this only: `left join Address a on  a.addressid = 24` Just sayin' ;-) Your `1 = 1` really has a feel of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming

Comment: @MichaelBuen Would you please take another look at my answer? 1 = 1 is VAAA's invention.

Comment: @MichaelBuen Also please be sure to check my comment at 23:17.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Ok.. you can't be faulted there. Anyhow, VAAA should be made aware that his solution needed be revisited, re-analyzed. It's a [Code Smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), and if that become a habit, it qualifies as [Cargo Cult Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)

Comment: @MichaelBuen My comment wasn't to say that `cross join` is not equivalent to `1=1` (which is trivially obvious) and wasn't actually addressed to you. I meant merely that it isn't the correct answer to the OPs problem (and by CROSS JOIN I also meant the `1=1` syntax since that's what it is). I apologize for my lack of clarity on just what I was criticizing. I wll rephrase: *According to my possibly-flawed-but-I-really-don't-think-so understanding of the questioner's actual needs*, logically `CROSS JOIN`ing between AddressTypes and Address is **completely wrong** (whether `1=1` or CROSS JOIN).

Comment: @ErikE I understand now, you are referring to logical cross joining in OP's invented answer. I looked at your comment's syntax rather than its semantic. I apologize for my misunderstanding too

Answer (score 0):

Use the LEFT OUTER JOIN, which returns one copy of matching records from both the left and right tables and non-matching records from both the tables. Here is the test code I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE AddressTypes(
    AddressType SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(50))

ALTER TABLE AddressTypes
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_AddressTypes_AddressType
    PRIMARY KEY (AddressType)


CREATE TABLE [Address] (
    AddressID INT NOT NULL,
    AddressType SMALLINT,
    Address1 NVARCHAR(50),
    Address2 NVARCHAR(50),
    City NVARCHAR(50),
    State CHAR(2))

ALTER TABLE [Address]
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Address_AddressID
    PRIMARY KEY (AddressID)

ALTER TABLE [Address]
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_address_addresstypes_addresstype 
    FOREIGN KEY (AddressType) REFERENCES AddressTypes(AddressType)


INSERT INTO AddressTypes VALUES (1, 'home'), (2, 'office'), 
                                (3, 'vacation'), (4, 'hotel')
INSERT INTO address VALUES (1, 1, 'piping', '1232', 'Austin', 'TX')

   -- Here is the query that outputs the result set.
    SELECT AT.AddressType AS [Type], A.Address1, A.Address2, A.City, A.State
    FROM AddressTypes AT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN address A
    ON AT.AddressType = A.AddressType
```